# How can I implement SSO Authentication with Active Directory in React App?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, azure, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on

I'm trying to create a front end application using React for an organization that already has a SSO (Single Sign On) system implemented using AD (Active Directory), and I want their employees to be able to login in my app using the same credentials.

Is there a way to do so using React only (if Yes, please How !) or should I use another technology like NodeJs for example.

Comment: Please provide more details. Currently, your question is unclear. Specifically, you seem to think React and NodeJs should be used exclusively when in fact, you use React for the frontend and NodeJs for the backend and you need both. Also, what kind of app this should be? A desktop app build with Electron or a web based app?

Comment: Thank u for ur answer. It's a web based app (it's a dashboard) developed in React, there's no backend, I get Data only from Csv and Xls Files, then I do some optimization before rendering. AND I want to add the SSO Auth so that only connected user could use it. And I want to know if there's a way to do so using only some react's package.

Comment: How your app is downloaded to a web browser? An app server, apache or nginx?

Comment: the app is under development, but it would be either nginx or apache.

Comment: Then, both apache and nginx have kerberos modules. For example, consult [`mod_auth_kerb`](http://www.microhowto.info/howto/configure_apache_to_use_kerberos_authentication.html) tutorial. This should fit your scenario.

Comment: I got it, Thank you for your effort.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the organization already has a SSO (Single Sign On) system implemented using AD (Active Directory), what you need to do is integrating Azure AD with your react app.

You can use [react-adal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-adal) or [react-aad-msal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-aad-msal), it depends on your requirement.

MSAL works with the Azure AD V2 endpoint, whereas ADAL works with the Azure AD V1 endpoint.

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/azure-ad-endpoint-comparison

Answer (score 0):

When your react app loads (say landing / login page), redirect to the server. (You could create an identical page on the server so the user does not feel the difference). On the server, read active user credentials from active directory/computer, encrypt relevant data (using your server's variant for cyptojs; Python has pycrypto), and switch back to your frontend url with the encrypted data. Decrypt the data in your react app (note that the server and client must share the same secret encryption/decryption keys). Now on the front end,  pass your data as normal login credentials as usual.